# × TypeError: react_linkedin_insight__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__.LinkedInTag.init is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tags, linkedin-api

When I try to call a function from the LinkedInTag package, I get the error
TypeError: react_linkedin_insight__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__.LinkedInTag.init is not a function

```
import { LinkedInTag } from 'react-linkedin-insight';
LinkedInTag.init("1234567", 'dc', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import LinkedInTag from 'react-linkedin-insight';
```

instead:

```
import { LinkedInTag } from 'react-linkedin-insight';
```

Comment: Yes that is indeed suggested https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkedin-insight. Adding sources to answer is always well received.